# Update only the changed properties of a complex angular model

Tags: angularjs

Lets say we have an Order model in Angular and we make a change to a LineItem quantity. We post the change to the server and now we need to update our client side model. However, if we replace the entire model it will refresh the page and potentially overwrite changes the user is currently editing such as another quantity value. Or the user deletes a LineItem while another update is in progress in the background.

```
$scope.order = result.data;
```

So how can I update only the Order and LineItem properties that changed such as the OrderTotal and the Quantity and Price of only the changed LineItem(s)?

Comment: "post the change to the server " - does every client side change need to go the server immediately? If this can wait, you could maintain the complete 'state' on the client side (even on save) and then when there's a navigation away from the page or when you'd think the user can't make any more changes, you make the server call.  I know this doesn't answer your question but a different thought.  Also, when you say 'it will refresh the page', why so? Its up to you to update the model based on the http response, you could do it selectively based on your client's new state if it has changed?

Comment: Think of amazon checkout where you see the list of items in your shoping cart. Each time you alter an item (change quantity, delete, etc.) you need to update the order server side and then refresh the page with the result as order total and items can change. But you have 100 items and you've only changed 1 item you end up refreshing / rerendering all the items client side when you update the order model wholesale.

Comment: You'd have to define some event, like a 'blur' or something which says - "this data is good, save it to the server".  Then your server has the right data.  The client "may" have changed in the meanwhile (something deleted)  - you could do some sort of 'id' based matching of what you've received from the server and whats there on the client - not necessarily your database id but some generated id that helps you keep track of line items and orders.  You'd have to trust either the client or the server with the 'last-modified' state and keep that updated. Did you have an idea to solve this?

Comment: I ended up writing a routine to update only properties that changed using lodash.

Comment: Glad you got it to work.